# Use Boolean algebra in tsql to avoid CASE statement or deal complex WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, boolean-operations

I came across a scenario,I will explain it with some dummy data. See the table Below

```
Select * from LUEmployee

empId   name    joiningDate
1049    Jithin  3/9/2009
1017    Surya   1/2/2008
1089    Bineesh 8/24/2009
1090    Bless   7/15/2009
1014    Dennis  1/5/2008
1086    Sus     9/10/2009
```

**I need to increment the year column by 1, only If the months are Jan, Mar, July Or Dec.**

```
empId   name    joiningDate derived Year
1049    Jithin  3/9/2009    2010
1017    Surya   1/2/2008    2009
1089    Bineesh 8/24/2009   2009
1090    Bless   7/15/2009   2010
1014    Dennis  1/5/2008    2009
1086    Sus     9/10/2009   2009
```

derived Year is the required column

We were able to achieve this easily with a case statement like below

```
Select *,
YEAR(joiningDate) + CASE WHEN MONTH(joiningDate) in (1,3,7,12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
from LUEmployee
```

But there came an added condition from onsite PM, Dont use CASE statement, CASE is inefficient.
Insearch of a soultion, We resulted in a following solution, a solution using binary K-map, As follows

---

If number 1 to 12 represents months from Jan to Dec, See the binary result
[image]

the Karnaugh Map way of expressing is given below.
[image]

the result will be

[image]

We need to realize the expression with sql server binary operations

```
eg: binary of 12 = 1100
    in the k-map, a = 1, b = 1, c = 0, d = 0
    Similarly, binary of 7 = 0111
    in the k-map, a = 0, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1
```

to get the left most bit (d), we will have to shift the bit towards right by 3 positions and the mask all the bits except LSB.

```
eg: ((MONTH(joiningDate)/8)&1)
```

Similarly, second bit from left (c), we need to shift the bit towards right by 2 positions and then mask all the bits except LSB

```
eg: ((MONTH(joiningDate)/4)&1)
```

Finally, each bit can be represented as

```
so  a = ((MONTH(joiningDate)/8)&1)
    b = ((MONTH(joiningDate)/4)&1)
    c = ((MONTH(joiningDate)/2)&1)
    d = (MONTH(joiningDate)&1)

a inverse = (((MONTH(joiningDate)/8)&1)^1)
b inverse = (((MONTH(joiningDate)/4)&1)^1)
c inverse = (((MONTH(joiningDate)/2)&1)^1)
d inverse = ((MONTH(joiningDate)&1)^1)
```

The final code will be

```
SELECT  *,
        YEAR(joiningDate) + CAST(
        ((MONTH(joiningDate)/8)&1)*((MONTH(joiningDate)/4)&1)*(((MONTH(joiningDate)/2)&1)^1)*((MONTH(joiningDate)&1)^1) |
        (((MONTH(joiningDate)/8)&1)^1)*(((MONTH(joiningDate)/4)&1)^1)*(MONTH(joiningDate)&1) |
        (((MONTH(joiningDate)/8)&1)^1)*((MONTH(joiningDate)/2)&1)*(MONTH(joiningDate)&1) 
        AS INT) [derivedYear]
FROM    LUEmployee
```

Result will be

[image]

---

**Question:
There may be simple and less complex ideas, please share it.**

I like to find a simpler one ,as well as share the idea.Here the possible conditions are 12 (12 months). We can use k-map for even bigger number of conditions..Felt like k-map is convenient for up to 64 conditions.

Comment: Never sacrifice readability for "performance" unless you have actual performance goals that your code currently isn't achieving. I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that your second solution will *never* outperform the first "inefficient because it uses `CASE`" solution.

Comment: From this question alone I can tell that the software development process in your org is broken. To answer your question: The case variant is efficient, more efficient then eny other variant in this question and its answers. Not sure what superstitious belief your PM holds.

Comment: I would actually wager that the complex boolean formula performs way worse than the initial case statement.

Comment: I agree with you all over the efficiency,As there is considerable calculations done in the 2nd sql. 
Will it be any different if we are having 1.02 million data in the table.?

Comment: The other reason, that I posted it is that we can use such calculations when we have to meet conditions with out a pattern.

Comment: The big cost in your original query is the fact that you're doing a table scan (because you're getting all the rows), not the `CASE`.  Now, if you're trying something funny like `ORDER BY CASE ...`, _that_ will have performance problems (because then the query has to hit the row to be able to determine the order, as opposed to just use an index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first reaction would be to defend the use of the `case` clause in this case. But if you are absolutely not allowed to use it, maybe you could simply add a table with the month and *increment* values:

```
LUMonthIncrement

Month   Increment
 1      1  
 2      0  
 3      1  
 4      0  
 5      0  
 6      0  
 7      1  
 8      0  
 9      0  
10      0  
11      0  
12      1
```

Then you can join in that table and just add the increment:

```
Select LUEmployee.*,
    YEAR(joiningDate) + LUMonthIncrement.Increment as derivedYear
from LUEmployee
    join LUMonthIncrement on MONTH(LUEmployee.joiningDate) = LUMonthIncrement.Month
```

This is unlikely to be much more performant though, because in order to join to `LUMonthIncrement` the `MONTH(LUEmployee.joiningDate)` expression must be evaluated for each row in the `LUEmployee` table.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you could do a `UNION` as you got 2 distinct subsets of your input set that don't depend on each other and the split criteria are well defined. So you could do something like:

```
Select *,
YEAR(joiningDate) + 1 as derived_year 
from LUEmployee
WHERE MONTH(joiningDate) = 1 OR MONTH(joiningDate) = 3 OR MONTH(joiningDate) = 7 OR MONTH(joiningDate) = 12

UNION 

Select *,
YEAR(joiningDate) as derived_year 
from LUEmployee
WHERE NOT (MONTH(joiningDate) = 1 OR MONTH(joiningDate) = 3 OR MONTH(joiningDate) = 7 OR MONTH(joiningDate) = 12)
```

Comment: Consider using `WHERE MONTH(joiningDate) IN (1,3,7,12)` instead of many OR's.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @user1429080's concept of a `Month` table one step farther, and turn it into a *range* table; this will allow for the elimination of the call to `MONTH()` in the join.  Assuming you have a Calendar table (which are *stupid* useful), you can build the query like this:

```
WITH LUMonthIncrement AS (SELECT month, increment
                          FROM (VALUES (1, 1),
                                       (2, 0),
                                       (3, 1),
                                       (4, 0),
                                       (5, 0),
                                       (6, 0),
                                       (7, 1),
                                       (8, 0),
                                       (9, 0),
                                       (10, 0),
                                       (11, 0),
                                       (12, 1)) m(month, increment))  

SELECT LUEmployee.empId, LUEmployee.name, LUEmployee.joiningDate, IncrementRange.year
FROM LUEmployee
JOIN (SELECT Calendar.calendarDate AS rangeStart, 
             DATEADD(month, 1, Calendar.calendarDate) AS rangeEnd,
             Calendar.year + LUMonthIncrement.increment AS year
      FROM Calendar
      JOIN LUMonthIncrement
        ON LUMonthIncrement.month = Calender.month
      WHERE Calendar.dayOfMonth = 1) IncrementRange
  ON LUEmployee.joiningDate >= IncrementRange.rangeStart
     AND LUEmployee.joiningDate < IncrementRange.rangeEnd
```

(Untested at the moment)

Yes, I'm still using an index-ignoring function (specifically, `DATEADD(...)`) - however, the subquery reference is likely to execute *first*, and will return 12 rows per-year, and the join to `LUEmployee` is free to use any index on **that** table (which is likely to be far larger than the result of the subselect).  Assuming `Calendar` has an index starting with `dayOfMonth` (it's a dimension table, it should...), `IncrementRange` should be built instantaneously.

(Note that I'm using a general range form here, which will be useful when dealing with types with a time portion attached.  This is handy for things like aggregating sales by month...  If you're using 2012 with a strict date type, you could potentially just straight join to the `Calendar` table directly on the date value, and skip dealing with the range.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bit logic here is a way

```
SELECT [empId], [name], [joiningDate]
     , [derived Year]
     = YEAR(joiningDate)
     + (1 - cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 8 as bit)) * (MONTH(joiningDate) % 2)
     - (cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 5 as bit))
     * (1 - cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 6 as bit))
     + (cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 12 as bit))
FROM   LUEmployee
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02ab5/20) with data expanded to have every month available

Explaining the bits

- `(1 - cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 8 as bit)) * (MONTH(joiningDate) % 2)` the first part return 1 for month (number) less then 8, the second part check the parity where 1 is odd, together they add 1 for 1,3, 5, 7; to remove the 5 we need
- `(cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 5 as bit)) * (1 - cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 6 as bit))` the first part return 1 for every value higher or equal 5, the second part return 1 per every value less then 6, the only intersection is 5
- `(cast(MONTH(joiningDate) / 12 as bit)` return 1 only for december

With all the option here, if I were in your position, I would check them all for performance and report back to my PM with the data, I'm quite sure there is a lesson to learn.