# Select average monthly count, grouped by a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, as I don't know how to best phrase this question.

Given a  query like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(i.created, '%Y-%m') as 'period',
COUNT(id) as 'total',
i.company_id
FROM invoice i
GROUP BY period, i.company_id
ORDER BY period DESC, total DESC
```

How can I return the average and/or mean count per month, grouped by company_id? It is important to only count those periods where there actually are any invoices.

Comment: Post some sample existing data and expected output.

Comment: Your query will currently not be able to use an index to answer the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` (read, very slow on large datasets).  If you have a Calendar Table (which are **stupid** useful for analysis purposes), you can turn this into a range query from a subselect - I show a related variant [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23761872/812837).  Note that it's good in general to avoid grouping by function results...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it's slow, I know. But the I needed this for only a single, once-off query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude zero months then add `HAVING` condition and then select `AVG()` for each company using your query as a base:

```
SELECT company_id, AVG(total)
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(i.created, '%Y-%m') as 'period',
          COUNT(id) as 'total',
          i.company_id
     FROM invoice i
     GROUP BY period, i.company_id
     HAVING COUNT(id)>0
  ) as T1
  GROUP BY company_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I probably need to use a temp table for that.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: You're right I've just missed `GROUP BY` in the end. Now fixed.

Comment: ...and +1'd.  Of course this wouldn't be an issue in most other systems, because they'd throw an error for the missing clause.  In MySQL, though...